# What is the method to get the public email of a User (C#, Graph API)?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

How do I get the public email address of a User through Graph API? How does the code look like in C#?

Important **Criteria** for this functionality is: The User isn't logged in or Authorized by Azure AD, Graph API...

I want to search for a user by First and Last Name. Is this possible?

Comment: Check [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). Use the feature "code snippet" to see the code of your request. Yes, you can search a user with first name and last name. Graph API is also available over `Odata` so you can write the OData query to get the result if you are not willing to use `GraphServiceClient` sdk.

Comment: Thank you, didn't knew this was available ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below returns the Email of a User filtered by DisplayName:

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetEmail")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetEmail([FromForm] string filter)
{
    var users = await graphClient.Users
        .Request()
        .Filter("startswith(displayName,'" + filter.ToString() + "')")
        .Select(e => new {
            e.Mail,
            e.DisplayName,
            e.GivenName
        }).GetAsync();

    if (users.Count > 0)
        return Ok(users[0].Mail);
    else
        return BadRequest("No user found");
}
```